# Rule for aligning Table Status indicators

Tags: tables, labels, alignment

Should status indicators in a table be centre aligned to each other or left aligned?

Option 1: Left aligned

[image]

Option 2: Center aligned

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all buttons the same size. That is, extend width for `STATUS 2` and `ERROR` buttons so it is the same as width of the `LONG STATUS` button. And center align the text in buttons.

Comment: What if we have a really long status and the rest of statuses are small in terms of text? User would totally lose focus while scanning such a list where the tiny status is center aligned in a large pill. I'd prefer left aligned view because the content can be easily scanned in such a view

Comment: @Sheraz Really long status is a bad design. It has to be easy to grasp in a matter of split second and hence must be reasonably small.